# sending data in correct format from react to node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a date object in my state coming from a react-datepicker component.

```
Sat Aug 28 2021 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

On Submit I am trying to pass this to my Node backend

```
try {
            const responseData = await sendRequest('http://localhost:5000/challenge/createChallenge', 'POST',
                JSON.stringify({
                    location: selectedOption,
                    format: selectedOption1,
                    date: selectedDate,
                    opponent: props.initialValues
                }),
                 
              {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token
              })
```

Using Stringify, it loses its form. The date loses 5.5 hours and becomes a string.

```
date: '2021-08-24T12:30:00.000Z'
```

how do I preserve the original IST format while sending it across? I tried removing the Json.stringify but it keeps erroring me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you send a date object to backend as below, your problem will be sorted out

```
date: new Date(yourDate)
```

and remove that JSON.stringify.

Comment: if i do that and try to receive on my route with console.log(req.body) it shows an empty object {}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right solution but I passed the data with to.String() and its now getting received accurately in NODE. Thanks.

```
JSON.stringify({
                    location: selectedOption,
                    format: selectedOption1,
                    date: selectedDate.toString(),
                    opponent: props.initialValues
                }),
```